# Erklärung für den Spruch "erstens kommt es anders..."

Tags: idiom

Den Spruch

> Erstens kommt es anders, und zweitens als man denkt.

verstehe ich zwar, was damit gemeint ist. Ich verstehe aber nicht die grammatische Konstruktion. Ist das eine Ellipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich nenne diese Art von Ausdrücken "sprachliche Kurzschlüsse".

Es handelt sich um eine scherzhafte Kreuzung (oder Vermengung) zweier eigentlich selbständiger gängiger Wendungen.

> Erstens... zweitens...
>
> Es kommt immer anders als man denkt.

Der komische Effekt entsteht dadurch, dass die Überraschung, die mit "es kommt immer anders als man denkt" nur beschrieben wird, durch das Hineinmischen des "erstens... zweitens"-Ausdrucks auch noch im Sprechakt selbst aktualisiert (vulgo: live erlebt) wird.

Die gleiche Technik der selbstreferentiellen Brechung verwendet der beliebte scherzafte Ausdruck:

> Ent oder weder!

Hier wird das gewöhnliche "Entweder - oder" auf Ebene des sprachlichen Ausdrucks selbst aktualisiert (erfahrbar gemacht), indem das "oder" auf die Bestandteile des "entweder" angewandt wird (und es dabei zerreißt).

Solchermaßen hochverdichtete, auf mehreren Ebenen gleichzeitig laufende Kommunikation löst im menschlichen Hirn besondere Reize aus, die (von vielen Hirnen) als angenehm empfunden werden. Vielleicht ist es ein bisschen wie ein erfrischender (oder erhellender) Kurzschluß.

Die Abbildung (oder Referenzierung) außersprachlicher Gegebenheiten im sprachlichen Ausdruck selbst ist ein Kernelement der Poetik.

Einfacher kann man auch sagen: Die Botschaft wird nicht nur über den Inhalt vermittelt, sondern auch über die Form.

Comment: *Erfahrbar gemacht* gefällt mir sehr gut. Vielleicht nicht so sehr ein *Kurzschluss* als vielmehr ein spontaner Energieschub durch einen extrem hohen Informationsgehalt.

Comment: @olafant  Oder Rohrreinigung durch einen kräftigen Schub Luft?

Comment: Wenn das Rohr verstopft war, möglicherweise auch das. :) Ein Kurzschluss ist ja ein Fehler im System. Fehlerhafte Verschaltungen sind aber nicht angenehm, sondern führen zu Verwirrung. Erfahrbar gemachte Information ist dagegen sehr effektiv. Also vielleicht kann man sagen, Zündung eines Geistesblitzes und der ist extrem angenehm?

Comment: @Olafant  Stimmt, "Kurzschluss" ist ein in manchen Aspekten unpassendes Bild, und "Geistesblitz" hat Vorteile. Auf der anderen Seite ist mir "Geistesblitz" aber auch wieder zu positiv, denn etwas von "defekt" sollte schon enthalten sein, da ja die semantisch-syntaktische Struktur der fraglichen Sätze (mindestens oberflächlich betrachtet) fehlerhaft ist. Insofern passt mir "Kurzschluss" doch wieder, denn einer ist etwas kaputt, und seits gibt es einen Funken, der die Umgebung erhellt.

Comment: Ich fasse mich kurz und zusammen: Geistesblitz durch sprachlichen Kurzschluss. Sehr schön. :)

Comment: @olafant .......  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Der Spruch beweist sich quasi selbst.

> Erstens kommt es anders und zweitens [...]

Es handelt sich hier um eine Aufzählung. Die Erwartung des Hörers ist es, ein weiteres Glied in dieser Aufzählung zu hören, vgl.

> Erstens regnet es morgen und zweitens habe ich ohnehin keine Lust ins Freibad zu gehen.

Hier führt der Sprecher zwei Argumente an, warum er morgen nicht ins Freibad gehen möchte.

Der Anfang der oben liegenden Konstruktion lässt also eine vergleichbare Ausführung anmuten. Doch es kommt *anders als man denkt*. Anstatt der Fortführung der Aufzählung, wird plötzlich ein Nebensatz eingeschoben.

Ein verwandter Ausdruck (von der Idee) lautet

> Dieser Satz kein Verb

Answer (score 1):

Die Grammatik dieses Spruchs ist absichtlich falsch, damit es sich komisch anhört und die Aussage selbst untermauert.

Comment: Ist nicht eigentlich die Grammatik (im Sinne von Morphologie und Syntax) des Satzes vollkommen richtig, doch es ist ein semantischer Bruch eingebaut?

Comment: Ich glaube, nach "erstens" und "zweitens" sollen eigenständige Aussagen stehen, aber die dürfen nicht mit der zweiten Hälfte eines Vergleichs anfangen.